# How do I detect the difference between Safari in Gmail Webview and Safari launched from Home Screen on iOS 11 when the User-Agent does not change?

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, safari

I maintain an app that sends notifications to users containing links to forms. Those forms have image-capturing controls. These controls break in Safari when the app is opened in Safari *through* another app in a webview.

Okay, so I look at having Javascript detect if it is in a webview and try to direct the user to open their browser directly. Except, well, the user agent strings for Safari when opened via Gmail and Safari when opened directly from the Home screen on iOS 11 are **identical**.

So, all approaches for detecting webviews I currently see on Google like NPM's `is-webview` and User-Agent/regex predicates do not work. The only meaningful difference I can see is that `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is undefined in the webview.

But knowing `getUserMedia` is undefined does not tell me if the user simply CANNOT use the controls, or if the user just needs to get directed to their default browser outside the scope of the app they used to access a notification.

Before we go through the trouble of decorating my links with additional data to track where users are coming from, is there a way to detect if Safari is opened via another app on iOS 11 if the user agent string does not change?

Comment: could you add a query string parameter or a different url for links in emails? and if its one of those different urls and the user is using ios then you know its likely a webview?

Comment: @floor We'd have to address what to do with old emails that are still out in circulation and lack said query string. That, and me knowing that I am 'likely' in a web view might give me false positives where a user genuinely has no user media support.

Comment: Yeah didn't consider the clean up. Maybe you could detect this server side from a reference url or some property on that http request that says its coming from gmail instead of somewhere else? I am just guessing sorry

Comment: @floor No worries. Thank you for chiming in!

Comment: did you find a solution for this? i'm having the same issue, trying to detect if my website was opened in webview from twitter app.